# Appending text in Java's JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I have a problem with my text area.

I use `jTextArea1.append("cleverly amusing");` to add the text..

FIRST APPEND:

[image]

then I use `jTextArea1.append("a fight");` to add the next text.

SECOND APPEND

[image]

What I Really want is to replace the "cleverly amusing" to "a fight". But I cannot do it. I tried to use the `jTextArea1.removeAll();` but there's no effect. How can I remove the "cleverly amusing" so that I can append the "a fight" to the first line.

NOTE: "WORD HINT" is fixed...

What can I do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your JTextArea will *only* contain "WORD HINT: ..." then use the [setText](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setText(java.lang.String))() method:

```
jTextArea1.setText("WORD HINT:\n" + word);
```

This will replace all the text with what you want.

BTW : [removeAll](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#removeAll())() is part of the Container class, and is not to remove text but child components.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `setText(String text)` instead of `append(String text)`?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `removeAll`, just call `setText()` with the first line you want and then you can append the additional data if you want.