# How to add text to a textArea instead of replacing it

Tags: java, string, swing, jtextarea

How can I add text to a `JTextArea` instead of replacing all of it?

I know about `setText(String)` but other than that I'm a bit lost.

Comment: What do you want to do? Append, prepend, insert in the middle somewhere?

Comment: here is similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852839/appending-text-in-javas-jtextarea

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use [the `append` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append-java.lang.String-) like this:

```
textArea.append(additionalText);
```

Comment: What is the `text` part?

Answer (score 4):

To insert string at any position you can use the component's Document.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws BadLocationException {
    JTextField f = new JTextField("foo bar");
    int offset = 7;
    String str = " baz";
    f.getDocument().insertString(offset, str, SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY);
    System.out.println(f.getText());
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
void append(JTextArea area, String newText){
        area.setText(area.getText() + newText)
}
```

Comment: -1 for re-inventing the wheel (api doc is a great resource to learn about available wheels :-)

Comment: area.setText(area.getText() + newText) is exactly what I was looking for, thanks to Pawel.