# Scanner How to Call inside the TextArea using Java

Tags: java

. i am creating simple question asking system in java. so wrote Scanner class How to Call inside the TextArea using Java. what tried so far i attached below. when the form is loaded question should display on the textarea.

```
public piz() {
    initComponents();
    ques();

    txtarea.setText(ques());
}

public void ques()
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter customer name: ");
    String name = in.nextLine();


}
```

Comment: So you want to turn the text area into a console? That is not a trivial thing to do. When writing a GUI, you should get inputs in a GUI way. Don't try to use the mindset you used to use in writing command line apps.

Comment: Please read this. There is no point in using Scanner with GUI. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html read this, and check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752307/how-to-retrieve-value-from-jtextfield-in-java-swing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use parameters to pass in a reference to the TextArea

```
    ques(txtarea);
}

public void ques(JTextArea txtarea)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter customer name: ");
    String name = in.nextLine();
    txtarea.setText(name);
}
```

However, you ideally wouldn't use the console to enter data into a GUI form

Comment: sir. when i run the program question displayed on console if i answer it answer displayed on textarea. i need to display the question on textarea

Comment: Then call `setText` with your question text

Comment: how will i write question need to displaed on GUI

Comment: I just told you how... Basically, forget Scanner. It shouldn't be used. Who told you to use it?

Comment: how should i write it sir.

Comment: this one question if answer more quesion side the textarea how to ask .if i answer the question another question will creation on the nextline

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12216494/how-to-add-text-to-a-textarea-instead-of-replacing-it

Comment: sir    public void ques(JTextArea txtarea)
{
    txtarea.append("cleverly amusing \n");

}

Comment: it displayed now question is if i enter anwser and enter how second question is created

Comment: how to create a new question sir