# How to print with JButton in JtextArea?

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

I have two buttons and I want to print their test continuously in one `JTextarea`, but when I print the first one and then I push the second, the last value gets deleted from the `Jtextarea`

This is my code:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   jTextArea1.setText("1"); 
}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   jTextArea1.setText("2");
}
```

I want to print `1` when I push key one and when I push key two, print `12`. But my program first deletes the last one, the last pushed key, then prints the new value. How can I fix this problem?

I'm using Netbeans IDE

Comment: You can refer to already available answer on SO.
[Refer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852839/appending-text-in-javas-jtextarea).

Answer (score 4):

use append function instead of setText:

`jTextArea1.append("2");`

Reference document:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

Just get the current text, and then add onto to:

```
jTextArea1.setText(jTextArea1.getText() + "2");
```

This will grab the text already in the text area, and uses string concatenation to add `2` onto the preexisting string.

Comment: There is a better method available: `JTextArea.append()`, instead of concatenation.

Comment: @root If this is what you use, you can accept it. However, the `append()` method would work better in this case.