# Posting data result from MySQL to JTextArea

Tags: java, mysql, jtextarea

I have data in a MySQL database and I need to show it in a JTextArea:

```
ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT `Name`, FROM `users" + "SELECT `Post`, FROM `history");
```

I need to show the result of this Query in the TextArea.

Comment: What is the question, or error?

Comment: I dont know how to show result, i was think something around
JtextArea.setText(ps); but thats complete BS :D

Comment: `ps` is something like a `List` or `Map`, isn't it? In that case you will want to iterate through that and add each item to a table or maybe just its string representation as a line in the `JTextArea`. Btw, why not JavaFX?

Comment: your query doesn't look correct. it support only one query per **preparedstatement**.

Comment: ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT `Name` FROM users") ;.... ps1=connection.prepareStatement( "SELECT `Post` FROM history");

Comment: and then follow the given solutions below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be something like this:

```
try{
    final String sql = "SELECT Name FROM users;";

    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    if(rs != null){
        while(rs.next()){
            String name = rs.getString(1);
            //Do something with name
        }
        rs.close();
    }
    ps.close();
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys <3 (no homo ;))

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

You have a malformed SQL-Query, like JAMSHAID IQBAL wrote in the comments. 
Here is an edited solution, that includes his improvements:

```
PreparedStatement psUserNames = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT Name FROM users;");
PreparedStatement psPosts = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT Post FROM history;")
```

**1. Extracting data from PreparedStatement:**

First you need to get a `ResultSet` from your PreparedStatement.
This is where all your requested data will be stored in:

```
ResultSet rsUserNames = psUserNames.executeQuery();
ResultSet rsPosts = psPosts.executeQuery();
```

then you need to extract the data as `String`s from this ResultSet. For example in a way like this (simplified example):

```
String username = new String();
String post = new String();
rsUserNames.next();
rsPosts.next();
username = rsUserNames.getString("Name");
post = rsPosts.getString("Post");
```

(Better iterate over all datasets in the ResultSet using a while loop and Exception handling. [Here](https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/) you can see an example)

**2. Writing data to JTextArea**

Then, a simple way to display the data strings to the JTextArea, is to use the [setText()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setText(java.lang.String)) or [append()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append(java.lang.String)) methods. For example:

```
JTextArea jtextAreaUserName = new JTextArea();
JTextArea jtextAreaPost = new JTextArea();
jtextAreaUserName.setText(username);
jtextAreaPost.setText(post);
```

---

Helpful links:

- [JDBC PreparedStatement example – Select list of the records](https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/)
- [Appending text in Java's JTextArea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852839/appending-text-in-javas-jtextarea)